# Why is the fetch API not being called sometimes?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, fetch, fetch-api

In the constructor class of my component, I make a fetch call to my database to get some data. Here is my constructor:

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)



    if (props.auth === false) {
        props.history.push("/")
    }

    //clearing reduce expenser before filling it up from the database to avoid duplicate data
    this.props.dispatch(resetExpenseReducer())

    //calling api to get all the expenses
    const url = "http://localhost:8080/getExpenses?email=" + encodeURIComponent(props.email)
    let h = new Headers({
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + props.token
    })

    let req = new Request(url, {
        headers: h
    })

    fetch(req).then((response, error) => {

        response.json().then((data, error) => {

            //filling the expenses in the reducer one by one
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                this.props.dispatch(addExpense({ description: data[i].description, note: data[i].note, amount: parseInt(data[i].amount), createdAt: parseInt(data[i].createdAt), id: data[i].id }))

            }

        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error)
        })
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error)
    })

}
```

I redirect to this component after my database has been updated (from another react component). As you can see, I first clear my redux store. Then, using the fetch API, I get all the data from my database and add it to the redux store. THIS WORKS ONLY SOMETIMES!

It works about 6-7 times in a row and then on the next redirect to this component, the redux store gets cleared BUT no data is added. After some testing, I realized that the fetch API is not called at all, but the code execution reaches just above the call. I have to refresh the page for it to start working again.

Please let me know any other information you require.

Comment: please create a simple sandbox with this example, it will be helpful for debugging

Comment: and how are you redirecting to this component, is it a main component or a sub component

Comment: Can you please explain to me what a sandbox is? I am redirecting it using props.history.push(url)

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid your code is somewhat anti-pattern. If you wanna use redux, then you should define action dispatchers in another file and redux store data should be conducted in another file, not in the component constructor.

If component unmount before fetch completed or reset controller  dispatch is done after fetch action dispatches, you won't be able to find reason. I think your code contains too many places for bugs. And I suggest you to check over life cycle functions as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have defined action dispatchers in another file but I am just calling them from the constructor. Is this wrong?
Also, when I tried to use a life cycle method such as componentWillMount, it told me this is unsafe and using it in the constructor is better.

Comment: Hmm. If your reset api requires DB operation, I think calling reset action dispatcher in the constructor and fetch api in the componentDidMount function is safe. If reset is just a offline operation, using fetch api in constructor is just fine.

Comment: The reset action dispatcher has nothing to do with the database. It just clears one of the states in my redux store.

Comment: Why not share your project in any way? via GitHub or Remote Control or any other means. Or just upload the file through any means. You can contact me via slack. Email address: savinkin0105@mail.ru